# Append an element with onclick parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I'm appending HTML elements with `clickevent`s via jQuery. 
The creation must be able to give these `clickevent`s variables, I end up in

> NOT DEFINED ERRORS.

```
function foo( bar ){
  // do something with bar
}; 

var bar = "lolbert";

$("#parent").append("<td onclick='foo(" + bar + ")'> Whatever </td>");
```

Of course, the last line ends in the element:

```
<td onclick='foo( lolbert )'> Whatever </td>
```

And the `clickevent` will cause a "lolbert is not defined" error. It's clear why this happens and that it doesn't work this way.
However, whats the correct way to handover variables for events created by jQuerys `.append()` ?

Comment: You forgot `'` after `onclick='foo(' + bar + ')'`>!

Comment: " missed:

$("#parent").append("<td onclick='foo('" + bar + "')> Whatever </td>");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the onclick handler functionally:

```
var bar = "foo";
$("#parent").append($('<td>Whatever</td>').click(
  function() {
    alert(bar);
  }));
```

Answer (score -1):

you can add onclick function like this in Js

> var x= "<button class='btn btn-package-1 mt-5 mb-4  packageId-" + value.packageId + "' onclick ="selectpackgenow('" + value.packageId
> + "');">Select"